# Phoenix Datepicker to only show available dates

Tags: datepicker, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, dynamic-forms

I am working on a simple booking system using the Phoenix framework. At the moment, I have a route for new bookings, displaying a date picker which takes the values from a "booking" model with the following attributes:

```
:time, Ecto.DateTime
:description, :string
belongs_to :user, Test.User
```

When I head to "bookings/new", my form is correctly displayed and I can pick whatever date I want. However, I am now trying to figure out how to remove unavailable dates from the picker.

[image: A screenshot of my form]

As far as I can see, the form is taking the values from [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto)'s DateTime primitive type, however coming from an OOP background I cannot figure out what resource I need to update in order to remove unavailable dates. Do I have to create a custom type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't block arbitrary dates in the default `DateTime` picker. You can restrict the range, but since they're independent `<select>` inputs, you can't hide specific combinations with the default implementation. You might want to look into a JavaScript/jQuery  date picker, or just do server side validation on form submit or using AJAX.

Comment: I see, I thought that would be the case. Thanks a lot, I will try to do this using AJAX or JQuery and update this if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't block arbitrary dates in the default `DateTime` picker. You can restrict the range (e.g. limit the years to 1234 to 1243 or months to January to June), but since they're independent `<select>` inputs, you can't hide specific combinations. Two ways to solve this that I can think of are:

1. Do the validation on the server. You can use AJAX to do the validation as soon as the user selects, without a page refresh, if you want.
2. Use JavaScript to restrict the range, either blocking selecting a taken date using custom JS, or use an existing, full fledged DatePicker / Calendar library.

Answer (score 3):

I am quite late to respond to this but I hope it will be able to help someone; you can use the `builder` option when using the `date_select` on forms.

```
<%= date_select f, :time, builder: fn b -> %>
      <%= b.(:day, prompt: "Date") %> /
      <%= b.(:month, prompt: "Month") %> /
      <%= b.(:year, prompt: "Year") %>
    <% end %>
```

That's how you can customize it if you need just the day, month and year. You can do the same with time too.